# The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133021.) + swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, core-data

I am currently using core data in my application. I have the following entities : Notification (to-1), People (to-many). The entities are as follows:

[schema for Notification entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU0b0.png)

[schema for People entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZGjg.png)

The People entity has a unique constraint which is the field id. Basically I'm going to receive notifications(which will be saved in Notification entity) from persons (which will be saved in People entity). I want to update the People entity if a person with a specific id sends more than one notifications and not create a new one (which will be duplicate).

When I am doing the above I get the following error:

The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 133021.)

Can someone please help me solve this issue. Below is my code and an example of the data that I am trying to save.

```
let entityNotification = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Notification", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)

    let newNotification = Notification(entity: entityNotification!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)

    newNotification.message = data["message"] as? String

    if let actor = data["actor"] as? [String : AnyObject]
    {
        let newPeople = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("People", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext) as! People

        newPeople.id = actor["id"] as? Int
        newPeople.name = actor["name"] as? String

        newNotification.actor = newPeople
    }

    if let designator = data["designator"] as? [String : AnyObject]
    {
        let newPeople = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("People", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext) as! People

        newPeople.id = designator["id"] as? Int
        newPeople.name = designator["name"] as? String

        newNotification.designator = newPeople
    }

    do
    {
        try newNotification.managedObjectContext?.save()
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Data model:

```
let notif = ["message" : "testing",
                 "actor" : ["id": 1, "name": "jim"],
                 "designator" : ["id": 2, "name": "dave"]]

    let notif1 = ["message" : "testing 1",
                 "actor" : ["id": 1, "name": "jim21"],
                 "designator" : ["id": 2, "name": "dave"]]
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you attempt to load an existing g `People` instance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The traditional way to resolve your issue of duplicate creation is to do a fetch request for a `Person` with that identity and update instead of creating new. This may also be the best option for you, testing will tell.

With unique constraints core data can do a merge for you, but you need to tell it how. Currently it's merging by throwing an error, which isn't so useful. You need to set the `mergePolicy` on the context to `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` and then try it out to see if the result is really what you want...